# How do you take user inputer upon executing your program through terminal?

Tags: c++, terminal, fstream

Part of an assignment requires me to define the input file names upon calling the program to be run through terminal, thus far I have my program implemented to take user input for the filename after its opened but how do we do it before including a flag of 0 or 1 input?

the idea

terminal: ./test.exe -filename- -flag-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by declaring your `main` like so

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

`argv`is an array of c-style strings and `argc` is how many c-style strings in `argv`.
Together they give you the program's command-line arguments

You can try this code as an example

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Have " << argc << " arguments:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Then when running your program you call it like so `Example.exe "./test.txt" 0` which will output

```
Have 3 arguments:
Example.exe
./test.txt
0
```

Comment: Thank you! very straight forward after testing it with the for loop and inputing different values it became clear :)